# pyspark setup issues on anaconda

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, anaconda, conda

Trying to learn to use pyspark with jupyter notebooks. created an env for pyspark and installed it in anaconda, python version is 3.10.8 and java version in the env is:

```
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.34+19-CA (build 17.0.3+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.34+19-CA (build 17.0.3+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

when opening jupyter labs and trying to run my first spark session i've used:

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JupNote").getOrCreate()
```

and get the error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\frezanlutu\Skills_Training\BigData\pyspark.ipynb Cell 3 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JupNote").getOrCreate()

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:228, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    226         sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230 # by all sessions.
    231 session = SparkSession(sc)

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:392, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    390 with SparkContext._lock:
    391     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 392         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    393     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:146, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    144 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145 try:
--> 146     self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                   conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148 except:
    149     # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:
    150     self.stop()

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:209, in SparkContext._do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    206 self.environment["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = os.environ.get("PYTHONHASHSEED", "0")
    208 # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209 self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210 # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211 self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:329, in SparkContext._initialize_context(self, jconf)
    325 def _initialize_context(self, jconf):
    326     """
    327     Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    328     """
--> 329     return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1585, in JavaClass.__call__(self, *args)
   1579 command = proto.CONSTRUCTOR_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1580     self._command_header +\
   1581     args_command +\
   1582     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1584 answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1585 return_value = get_return_value(
   1586     answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1588 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1589     temp_arg._detach()

File c:\Users\frezanlutu\.conda\envs\pyspark-env\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

i've also tried:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").appName("JupNote").getOrCreate()
```

after looking for some solutions but that produces the same error. anyone know if i'm missing anything or doing anything wrong?

Comment: are you using windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which spark version are you using? If you are using Spark < 3.3.0, it only support Java 8. You may check https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/#downloading

Comment: Im Using 3.2.1, so should i upgrade my pyspark version or downgrade my Java? as the site just says "Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+ and R 3.5+. Java 8 prior to version 8u201 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.2.0."

Comment: @FreddieBL As you're using 3.2.1 version, you should downgrade your java version at least to 11. If you want to use the Java 17, then you should upgrade your spark to at least 3.3.0 version.

Comment: @FreddieBL Can you run your spark now?

Comment: Downgraded to 11 and its seemingly resolved all the issues, thanks